# How can I check if specific USB device(not storage device) is connected to Windows with batch scripting?

Tags: windows

I would like to run my script at Windows startup, only when a specific USB device is connected.

Is there anyway to achieve this in batch scripting?
Or is there any better way?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  We don't write code.  We try to improve/fix what you created so long as you have provide you a concrete example which shows effort put forth on your part.  Example:  This code here results in the following error message....I googled and think the problem could be this but also might be that...please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get devcon.exe for your platform](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/182.how-to-obtain-the-current-version-of-device-console-utility-devcon-exe.aspx)

get identification string of USB device you want to monitor

```
devcon find USB*
```

than replace xxxx and yyyy strings in following command by your own and run it. If errorlevel 0, at least one requested device is present. If errorlevel 1, no device is present.

```
devcon status "USB\VID_xxxx&PID_yyyy" | findstr /C:"matching device(s) found">NUL
```